# HTML,CSS Remaining traces on the page after the animation video is finished

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the smoke animation is finished, it stays a little on the bottom right. I don't want to see this and try to fix this.

How do I solve this problem? I showed the problems in the picture. Additionally, the smoke.mp4 link is below.

[image]

```css
body 
  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background:black;
  }

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
}

video {
  object-fit: cover;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: animate 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    filter: blur(10px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

h1 span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 3.75s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
```

```html
<section>
       <video src="smoke.mp4" autoplay muted></video>

  <h1>
    <span>W</span>
    <span>E</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>M</span>
    <span>E</span>
  </h1>
</section>
```

smoke video link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ncI67cgjRGoQZHF6I0dEpXwvFwCKxFPK/view

Comment: I made a snippet. It is not clear what the problem is, at least not in Chrome

Comment: The video file must also be in the folder. (link above)

Comment: that does not seem to be possible in a snippet when you use google drive

Comment: Not sure about the white box in the down-right corner, but the remainder of the smoke could be removed by making the video a little bit longer. The video is cut off with a small amount of smoke left on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your video's last frame is not completely black. What you can do is listen for the [`ended` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) of the video and then hide it.

```js
document
  .querySelector('video')
  .addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    e.target.style.display = 'none';
  });
// ofcourse you could toggle a class that hides it
// instead of setting an inline style
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
}

video {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: animate 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    filter: blur(10px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

h1 span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 3.75s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

h1 span:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <video src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ncI67cgjRGoQZHF6I0dEpXwvFwCKxFPK" autoplay muted></video>

  <h1>
    <span>W</span>
    <span>E</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>M</span>
    <span>E</span>
  </h1>
</section>
```